# Could not load type 'CSASPNETFormViewUpload.Default'

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, formview

I've downloaded this formview sapmle from this link - [Link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETFormViewUpload-471ecc6e)
But when I'm trying to run it in VS2010 its giving the error!

Default.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CSASPNETFormViewUpload.Default" %>
```

Image.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Image.aspx.cs" Inherits="CSASPNETFormViewUpload.Image" %>
```

While running this why I'm getting the error-

Could not load type 'CSASPNETFormViewUpload.Default'.
Could not load type 'CSASPNETFormViewUpload.Image'.

[image: Errors]

Please suggest something.

[image: error in codebihind]

Comment: I have no issue running this project. Probably there is something else wrong. 'Could not load type' looks more like a runtime error than a build error to me. Have you build (F6) in Visual Studio?

Comment: No its not F6, its  ctrl+shift+B.

Comment: @Steven showing you the image of error above.

Comment: Have you unzipped the package correctly? Have the files been "unblock" on unzipping? Check the files in Windows Explorer, right-Click, if on the lower-right corner is a button "Unblock", this could be the issue.

Comment: Should I unblock each file?

Comment: I'start with the file default.aspx.cs and see if it makes any difference while building.

Comment: I'm getting this error in default.aspx.cs-  The name fvPerson doesnot exist in the current context.

Comment: Then ttry to unbloack Default.aspx.designer.cs and Default.aspx.cs too

Comment: Done it still the same errors.

Comment: Please see the error in code behind in above image.